# Android LayoutParams not being updated properly

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin

So I have a scroll view, and I need to adjust the height of my scroll view to make sure it stays above a modal pop-up view. I can't use a constraint layout because this modal pop-up view is not a child of the same view parent. So I'm trying to dynamically update my scroll views layout params so its height is small enough to not get hidden behind the modal pop-up.

The pop-up view height can change at points so I have a callback that returns the new height of the modal view anytime it changes. In that callback I adjust the scroll views height like so:

```
someModalView.onHeightChanged = { newViewHeight ->
    Log.d("TESTHEIGHT", "PreHeight = ${scrollView.height}")
    scrollView.layoutParams = FrameLayout.LayoutParams(scrollView.width, scrollView.height - newViewHeight)
    scrollView.requestLayout()
    Log.d("TESTHEIGHT", "PostHeight = ${scrollView.height}")
}
```

Unfortunately the above code seems to do nothing and in my logs I can see that the PreHeight prints the same height as the PostHeight. Any reason the views height isn't getting changed?

Also, I did debug it and make sure that newViewHeight is not 0, and it isn't, it's ~800

---

Ended up making it work by adding padding to the view rather than changing its height like so:

```
someModalView.onHeightChanged = { newViewHeight ->
    scrollView.setPadding(0, 0, 0, newViewHeight)
}
```

This works exactly how i needed it to, however it doesn't really answer the question so I will just leave it in the answer for anyone else who it might help. But it would still be nice to know why changing the layout params wouldn't update the views height.

Answer (score 0):

try to see it works for you

```
val params = scrollView.layoutParams;
params.height = scrollView.height - newViewHeight
scrollView.layoutParams = params
```

Comment: Seems to give me the same results

Answer (score 0):

Once I needed to get the height of the softKeyboard to update my view:

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ScrollView sView;
    private int heightDiff;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        sView = findViewById(R.id.scrollView);
        //Here we get the height of soft keyboard by observing changes of softKeyboard height.
        sView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                heightDiff = sView.getRootView().getHeight() - sView.getHeight();
            }
        });


        final EditText email = findViewById(R.id.eemail);
        EditText firstName = findViewById(R.id.efirstname);
        firstName.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if (!isVisibleWhileSoftKeyboardShowing(email) && hasFocus) {
                    sView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            sView.smoothScrollBy(0, 200);
                        }
                    }, 500);
                }

            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * check if a view is currently visible in the screen or not
     *
     * @param view
     * @return
     */
    public boolean isVisibleWhileSoftKeyboardShowing(final View view) {
        if (view == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!view.isShown()) {
            return false;
        }
        final Rect actualPosition = new Rect();
        view.getGlobalVisibleRect(actualPosition);
        final Rect screen = new Rect(0, 0, getScreenWidth(), getScreenHeight() - heightDiff);
        return actualPosition.intersect(screen);
    }


    /**
     * to get screen width
     *
     * @return
     */
    public static int getScreenWidth() {
        return Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
    }

    /**
     * to get screen height
     *
     * @return
     */
    public static int getScreenHeight() {
        return Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;
    }
}
```

heightDiff is the height of softKeyboard. There was 2 edit texts. I wanted to scroll if softKeyboard hided the lower one. Hope this is similar to your case.